# Ab-initio Graph to Java conversion

Tags: ab-initio

I want to convert Ab-initio graph to Java. Can someone please suggest if he or she has worked on this earlier and what should be the approach for this.

Comment: Any mapping technique will do.  Parse the input into an in-memory object and use the template technology of your choice to generate the output.  The details will depend on the input and output formats.

Comment: I have existing mapping/graphs in Ab Initio , which need to be converted to Java.

Comment: I also wanted to check whether Abinitio mapping/graphs can be exported to xml similar to Informatica.